# Arduino caching serial connection?

Tags: python, serialization, arduino

I am trying to communicate with my arduino from my computer with python. I have the arduino sending a `1` over serial at the end of `setup()` as it is run when a serial connection is established. Then, in python, I listen for that `1` before sending anything to the arduino.

Here is my arduino code:

```
int ledPin = 2;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.write(1); // Ready signal
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // For troubleshooting
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}

void loop(){

}
```

And my python:

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

ser.read(1) # Arduino sends one byte when serial connection established
print("Serial connected")
ser.close()
```

This works perfectly the first time I connect. I get this:

```
$ python pyserialtest.py
Serial connected
```

But the second time I run the script, nothing happens. The script just hangs. I think this is because the serial connection is being cached either By python or by the arduino therefore `setup()` isn't run. I have tried to remedy this by calling `ser.close()` at the end of my script in an attempt to clear the connection but it still doesn't work.

My arduino is the uno rev 3. Python version 2.7.6.

Comment: I have temporarily fixed this by setting the serial read timeout in python to 4 seconds.

Comment: To make sure I understand, what's the sequence of events (1) run script, (2) boot arduino, (3) run script and it hangs?

Comment: Sequence is (1) boot arduino, (2) run script and it works, (3) run script again and it hangs.

Comment: try `sudo python pyserialtest.py`

Comment: @ahmed Doesn't help. Unfortunately, sudo is not the answer to everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the Arduino `setup` method is run only a single time. Consequently, the second time you run your script, your script is awaiting the one byte serial confirmation, but it's going to wait forever, since the `setup` method has already run and sent that byte to first instance of the script. If you were to reboot your Arduino at this point, it would run `setup` again, send the confirmation byte, and your script would proceed.

Comment: Wrong. The `setup()` routine is run every time the processor starts, which is after: 1) power on, 2) the reset button on the board is pressed, or 3) a serial connection over the built-in USB port is opened. This is called auto-reset. See http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection

Comment: I may be mistaken. If you manually reboot the Arduino, does the script still hang?

Comment: No, but the script has to be hanging when I hit the button.

Comment: Based on that behavior, maybe it's not actually resetting due to the serial connection. When you open the script the second time, do you still get the heartbeat on the LED?

Comment: No. No heartbeat the second time. It is for this reason that I think the arduino is caching the connection. Maybe it doesn't bother resetting because it thinks it's still connected.

Comment: @Marcel I'm guessing that *"making a serial connection over the built-in USB port"* means making a physical connection, i.e. plugging the cable in. So unless you physically remove the cable and plug it back in, the `setup` function is not going to run again.

Comment: I think this applies to starting a connection with python. I get the heartbeat when I run the python script.